# Android collapse any view on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I don't have an action bar in my activity. At the top is a search bar and below that are a couple of chips, which assist filtering.

I want to collapse just the chipgroup on scrolling. Is this possible with an animation?
The only things I found were using the action bar.

Comment: What about the expansion?